# Master API & Types

Tags: ros, master, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While exploring the Master API, I experienced something I didn't expect :

After the last publisher ( and all subscribers ) on a topic is gone, the topic still has a type and is still returned by getTopicTypes().

Did anyone experienced this ? Is it expected ?
Or is there some more complex behavior, like timeout or so ?

If it s expected, then it means a topic cannot change type ?

Also any reason why there isn't a similar getServiceTypes() API ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223546/master-api-&-types/) by [asmodehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/23141/asmodehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not surprised that topic types persist in the master even after the topic is gone. In general, the master does not implement timeouts; it relies on nodes to unregister themselves when they shut down (yes, this lack of timeouts can be considered a bug).

I would be surprised if topics couldn't change types, once all of the publishers and subscribers are gone. (It's also possible to run multiple publishers with different types on the same topic; I'm not sure what type the master returns in this case. Either way, this is generally very confusing for the subscribers and results in lots of errors).

I don't think the master tracks service types; `getSystemState()` is not documented as returning the service type.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0